# How to change jointly values under columns range and serately in other column

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have this dataset

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7), V = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0), Mus = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), R = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    E = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), S = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), t = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0), score = c(1, 0.4, 1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`5` = 5L, 
`12` = 12L, `15` = 15L, `21` = 21L, `22` = 22L, `23` = 23L, `34` = 34L, 
`44` = 44L, `46` = 46L, `52` = 52L, `56` = 56L, `57` = 57L, `58` = 58L
), class = "omit"))
```

I would like to remove rows equal to zero in columns that ranges from the second to the sixth columns and that in last column have 0.4. This would imply - if possible - to readjust the ID value properly.

My expected outcome would be:

```
ID   Vid   Mus   Rea   Ema   SMS   tel   MMT
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0   1  
2     3     1     1     1     0     1     0   1  
3     4     1     1     1     1     1     1   0.4
4     6     1     1     1     0     1     0   0.4
5     7     0     0     1     0     0     0   0.4
```

that does not have the second ID rows from the original dataset. Does anyone has any clue for doing this via dplyr or another iterative method (for loop and so on)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if_all()` in `filter()` like you can use `across()` in other functions. Just use `row_number()` to regenerate `ID`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(
    !(if_all(
      .cols = V:t,
      .fns = ~ .x == 0
    ) & score == 0.4)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    ID = row_number()
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 × 8
#>      ID     V   Mus     R     E     S     t score
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0   1  
#> 2     2     1     1     1     0     1     0   1  
#> 3     3     1     1     1     1     1     1   0.4
#> 4     4     1     1     1     0     1     0   0.4
#> 5     5     0     0     1     0     0     0   0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowSums` with `filter`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(!(rowSums(across(V:t)) == 0 & score == 0.4)) %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number())

     ID     V   Mus     R     E     S     t score
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0   1  
2     2     1     1     1     0     1     0   1  
3     3     1     1     1     1     1     1   0.4
4     4     1     1     1     0     1     0   0.4
5     5     0     0     1     0     0     0   0.4
```

Comment: yes, thank you so much. But this would mean to readjust the ID sequence

Comment: Oh right. Use `row_number` to readjust. See edit

Comment: `score == 0.4` beware of floating point errors